# R, variables in df with different format?

Tags: r

I have an R question that is bothering me for a while. I have a dataframe (df) that contains the variable A and B which are both numeric (positive on that).

```
Assumptions:
 - A and B can be equal
 - A can be 0
 - B can be 0
```

Then I perform the following calculation:

```
df$C <- (( df$A / (df$B - df$A)) -1 ) * 100
```

The result (df$C) is a numeric vector, which makes all sense I guess. Although I notice that within df$C, some variables are numerical (an example would be 5) and others (those that contain ".", such as 1.5) are interpreted as categorical.

Practical example (lets assume that the A has the same value in all its length. The same goes for variable B ):

```
df$A <- 3
df$B <- 2
```

thus:

```
 ID   A   B   C
  1   3   2   400
  2   2   2   Inf
  3   4   2   -300
  4   10  1.5 -217.6471
```

Then I subset the data like this:

```
subset(df, df$C == X)
```

where X is obviously a value. Although, I found that if X == 400 then it works, else, if X == -217.6471 it does not work. Instead, I need to use X == "-217.6471", which (correct me if I am wrong) means the variable is categorical. Or, in other words:

```
 ID   A   B   C
  1   3   2   num
  2   2   2   Cat
  3   4   2   num
  4   10  1.5 Cat
```

How is this even possible?

Still, I have another question. When A and B are equal, apparently I get "Inf", "-Inf" and some other random values (which, I assume, its trash).

Can someone please explain me whats wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is not clear as it is. If you have a data.frame object each column can be of one type i.e. either numeric or character (categorical). In column B in your example `1,5` is character but that would result in an error and not the results you have in column C. Which makes me think it is all numeric. When comparing numbers you should use `identical` or `all.equal`. If A and B are equal you are dividing by 0 which is why you get Inf or -Inf.

Comment: if you try `1 == "1"` you will get `TRUE` because the numeric `1` was first converted to character `"1"` and then compared, similarily when a numeric and character is colinked, numeric turns to be a character

Comment: Hi @LyzandeR, Sorry it was 1.5 and not 1,5. You are right, supposedly, a df has all the columns with the same format and in fact this is the case. Both A and B are numeric. The same goes with C. With the examples I gave I am trying to illustrate the variety that the real scenario can present and yes, once I divide A by 0 I should get Inf or -Inf, which is true for some values. Although sometimes it gives me a huge value (different from -Inf of Inf). I cannot fully represent it here because my dataset has some gigabytes and some 100k rows with real customer data. Although I am positive on this

Comment: Hi @joel.wilson. What you say makes all sense to me. Although how should I interpret the value -883198108173860992 that the real dataset holds? This in fact can be used in subset as it is, although for subsetting the dataset using the value -189299.99999997 I have to use "". I find this very weird.

Answer (score 1):

I replicated what you did but I'm not getting the same results.

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(3,2,4,10), B=c(2,2,2,1.5))  
df$C <- (( df$A / (df$B - df$A)) -1 ) * 100

> subset(df, df$C=="-217.6471")
[1] A B C
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> subset(df, df$C==-217.6471)
[1] A B C
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

If I do `subset(df, df$C=="-217.6471")` I do not get the 4th row. Nor do I get the 4th row if I do `subset(df, df$C==-217.6471)` and this is likely because the 4th value for `df$C` is not exactly -217.6471 but rather has been rounded to the fourth decimal.

```
> subset(df, df$C==Inf)
  A B   C
2 2 2 Inf
> class(df$C)
[1] "numeric"
```

If I do `subset(df, df$C==Inf)` then I get the 2nd row of `df`, as expected. `df$C` is an entirely numeric column; it is not composed of some numeric and some categorical values. You can see this by doing `class(df$C)` or `str(df)`. I don't think this is even possible for data frames in R. In order to have a mix of different types of variables together you need to create a `list` in R.

Comment: Hi. It does not make sense to me either. I will now use real values to better explain my problem:
it I do a table(df$C) I get: 
 -Inf -883198108173860992 -877023250872270848 
  76               1                              1                             
-581091895279616256     -189299.99999997 
                    1        1
When I subset data for (-883198108173860992) it is no problem. Although, I can only subset the dataset by -189299.99999997 using "". (I have confirmed this). Plus, I checked the A and B values for the  -Inf and they are equal, but its the same to the remain values

Comment: Seems odd, not sure what more to say. Are you sure `df$A` and `df$B` are also numeric columns? If not then that may be what's messing up when you create `df$C`.

Comment: O think something is messing with C when it is being created.. I am positive about all variables being numeric.. well, round eliminates the problem around the numeric and categorical (but because it hasn't any kind of decimal places at all), still, when A and B are equal, sometimes I get -Inf or Inf and sometimes I get a big value.. to be honest it's like 4 or 5 rows in 100k.. but it's still pretty weird

Answer (score 1):

I think this fixes it. You need to explicitly round any time you use multiplication and division:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(3,2,4,10), B=c(2,2,2,1.5))  
df$C <- round((( df$A / (df$B - df$A)) -1 ) * 100, 4)

subset(df, df$C== "-217.6471")
A   B         C
4 10 1.5 -217.6471
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think in R you can have a column with different data types. Usually in R categorical are qualitative variables, that have factor as a datatype. Categorical can also be numeric, however datatype will still be factor.

Can you provide a data frame sample, because this question is not really clear. also show us expected output. Thanks

Comment: Hi, well, yes you are right. As far as I know you cannot have different data types within the same column. Although, performing a table in df$C real data I get 
-883198108173860992 -877023250872270848
           1                                   1
 -581091895279616256     -189299.99999997 
           1      1
I can subset the dataset using the first three values (so the output will be one line because there is only one observation for each value). For the 4th value I can only subset the dataset using "".

Comment: You need to round any time you use multiplication and division. See above

Comment: Right, it's true. But rounding solves the problem partitially.. because It cuts off the decimal places. No "." No problem, it understands it as numeric.. still, when A and B are equal, sometimes I get -Inf or Inf.. other times I get these extreme values. Dunno why :-/